# Backup/Restore with pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, pythonanywhere, pgadmin-4

I'm not sure that I actually have a problem, but I am confused.  I wanted to move a PostgreSQL database from PythonAnywhere to an AWS RDS server.  I connected to both servers with pgAdmin from my Windows PC (ssh tunnel with PuTTY).  I then did a backup of the database from PythonAnywhere and then did a restore to a clean database on the RDS server.

The backup had no issues, but, while the restore seemed to run fine, pgAdmin showed the process "Failed".  The database on the RDS server looks fine.  I checked row counts on a few tables, and they matched what I had on PythonAnywhere.  I don't see any messages in pgAdmin other than that the process failed.  I don't see anything in the pgAdmin logs to indicate what might be wrong.  Do I have a problem?  Should I use a command line restore instead?

Thanks for any insights.

--Al

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using cli is a better way, the ide may not give full errors. [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) will work for you. Maybe you should build a [EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/tr/ec2/) for this job.

Comment: Thanks.  I did that, and I could see the errors, which turned out to not really matter.